# In an app made for Java 8 Standard Env, IntelliJ IDEA errors in appengine-web.xml with 'Element must be declared'

Tags: google-app-engine

In an app made for the Google App Engine Java 8 Standard Environment, IntelliJ IDEA produces an error in `appengine-web.xml`, stating that 'Element appengine-web-app must be declared'. This doesn't prevent anything, but I'm wondering if there's also anything to change or add for IDEA to recognize the element.

[image: IDEA showing appengine-web-app element error]

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA you are on? And is it Ultimate or community edition?

Comment: @Vivek it's "IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-232.9921.47, built on September 12, 2023".

Comment: Thanks, I have the same version of IntelliJ IDEA and ultimate edition too, and have an app-engine standard app with Java 8, but didn't have this message in my `appengine-web.xml`, wondering what it could be?

Comment: Maybe the Google CloudCode plugin, what version are you on? I've 23.9.3-api-version-222?

Comment: @Vivek it's also the latest, 23.9.3-api-version-222, and the problem persists.